# How to approach designing a 30GHz bandpass filter?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, filter

***How would one approach designing bandpass filters in the 3GHz - 30GHz range**, each with ~2.4GHz bandwidth, for a 50Ω spectrum analyzer or sampling oscilloscope? I've learned how to implement some simple RF designs in the 1GHz-5GHz range, and some of what to look out for.*

- What circuit topologies are used? (Eg. coupled line vs capacitive-gap resonator vs capacitive coupled shunt resonator.)
- Any active components?
- What bandwidths and falloffs can be expected?

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: @LeonHeller, Nope. Besides, it's way too fun to be homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 30ghz, there likely are no commonly used active filter topologies.  However you can use galium arsenide FETs in this region to build various circuits (PA, LNA, mixer, VCO, etc), never seen them used at 30ghz but have seen them used for 24 Ghz I would think you could extend their operation to 30Ghz if care was taken.

Passive filters will definitely be implemented with microstrip structures, lumped elements will not be useful at these frequencies.  You'll also need to find a very good substrate to work at 30Ghz.

Falloff is dependent on the topology you use and the number of poles in the filter much as it would be at lower frequencies.  For instance Chebyshev filters are common.

My only experience near such frequencies was a 24Ghz FMCW radar front end, that used GaAs FETS for the PA, VCO, mixer, a hairpin bandpass filter and was built on Roger 5870 substrate.  I didn't do the RF design this was an externally sourced design and we ended up using a 10.5Ghz variant of it.

My initial thought is that your desired bandwidth is really wide, and that will greatly complicate the design.

Your best bet is to get a couple books on RF filter design, make sure your up on your calculus and start running some simulations using various topologies.  [Ansoft Designer](http://www.ansoft.com/products/hf/ansoft_designer/) and [Microwave Office](http://web.awrcorp.com/) are the two simulation packages that i've bumped into in the past for RF circuit simulation.  I believe they both have free trials.

Comment: Fantastic info, Mark! I also thought a stable passband from 3-30GHz would be unmanageable (and not useful), but would like to try out some in that range. My *5-year plan* is to build a ~3GHz spectrum analyzer with external mixers, so BPFs couldn't have more than a ~2.4GHz passband. I will definitely look into everything you've mentioned.

Comment: at frequencies under 3ghz constraints are much easier, you can use simpler/cheaper substrate.  You'll still be designing mostly with micro-strip structures for filters but there are a lot more off the shelf parts like PA/LNA etc as well as design information due to the high use of the 2.4Ghz spectrum.

Comment: Good to know. I'm hoping to make external mixers to mix RF down to <3GHz IF from a few fixed frequencies. 30GHz is the top of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer, but, I would think that 3 - 30 GHz is a wide enough passpand that you can implement the bandpass filter by cascading a low-pass filter (at 30 GHz) and a high-pass filter (at 3 GHz). Which simplifies your problem somewhat. But it doesn't mean that designing either of the two component filters for operation out to 30 GHz will be easy.

With this wide a band, you will probably not be able to use any simple transmission line structures to implement your filter, because that generally only works over a fraction of an octave. Some kind of distributed structure (multiple stubs of different lengths connected periodically to your main line) may be possible.

Comment: Thanks! The plan is to make several filters and mixers, each with a ~2.4GHz passband, from 3-30GHz to mix down for a 3GHz spectrum analyzer. I'll clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

30 odd GHz is quite a bit of bandwith.

There may be some useful info for you [{here}](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas.htm).